# Button text position differs from browser

Tags: html, css, button, browser

Button text position differs whether it in firefox/chrome or opera/ie.
I have a button and text in it. In opera it goes little bit lower than in firefox.

```
HTML:

    <button>
        some
    </button>

CSS:
    button {
        width:145px;
        height:36px;
        border: 0;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

How can I prevent this "jumping" of text button?

Also a bonus question: may be someone knows how to prevent this different visions of font-weight in browsers?(see the images)

[image: Opera]

[image: firefox]

P.S. I googled it - hadn't found the answer

EDIT: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3s4n1u3d/)

EDIT_2: Browsers are updated to the last versions. (May be excluding the IE, but the issue is in opera too). OS: Windows 8.1 Industry Pro

Comment: Regarding to the font-weight question, i encountered the same problem with my website, my guess is browser's by default has their own settings for those kind of things for instance in your situation the font-weight, in my case the font style was different, it's because the setting of the browser's font was changed by the user to his type of font which he likes. I can't really explain the whole idea but i hope this helps.

Comment: Just set: `font-weight: bold;` instead of `600`

Comment: It is strange, because after add into button a span element and give it pos:absolute; left:0; top:0; it just have the issue... it is seems like in opera text "top:2" or something.

Comment: What version of browsers are you testing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the problem.

I used font-family "Myriad Pro" which was installed with Photoshop. Every browser seems like renders different this font, so after font-family change the problem has gone.

Quite tricky to find but easy solution...

Answer (score 5):

You haven't defined the font-size and font-weight, so the different browser is taking button font as it's own. Setting these explicitly solves the problem:

```
button {
        width:145px;
        height:36px;
        border: 0;
        color:#fff;
        font: 16px normal Arial;/*change as per your requirement*/
    }
```

---

**Update:**

I came to the across solution for the key problem with button tag. The default style for button is `display: inline-block;`.

And the different browsers do have different vertical-aligning (top, middle, ...), thus fixing vertical-align to the button will fix the issue.

So, far for the button css, add this line of code:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Not so. See the fiddle i added - it has all the font things.

Comment: Make a fiddle to test it please.

Comment: I just tried to add "line-height" and it didn't help. So I need proove that is really can work, because I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately the same... May be I got something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> In Explorer Windows and Opera there turns out to be a difference
>   between font-weight: 600 and font-weight: bold...

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tests/iewin_fontweight.html

Use `font-weight: 700;`.

```css
button {
 position: relative;
 width:145px;
 height:36px;
    line-height: 36px;
 border: 0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:700;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Verdana", sans-serif, serif;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00a885 49%, #009979 54%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00a885 49%, #009979 54%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00a885 49%, #009979 54%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00a885 49%, #009979 54%);
 margin:0;
 margin-top:14px;

 box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>some</button>
```

Comment: It's cool, but it worries me the least. I want to know why the text is jumping from up to down dependence the browser.

Comment: Post versions of the browsers and which OS you use. And screenshots.

Comment: Screenshots are in the post, browser versions are the last. But I will add in the post, thanks

Comment: I don't see any positioning issues except that the buttons are of different size on the screenshots.

Comment: Do you see the text in buttons? The gradient is the same, but the place where word is crossed - not the same.

Comment: try to add line-height: 36px; Although even without that the result from my code snippet looked the same in FF, IE, Chrome and Opera. you can also try to remove "Myriad Pro".