# Give CSS parameter to certain web-engine

Tags: html, css, browser

Is there a way to give a CSS parameter to element only to apply in some browser engines?
As we can specify a -moz-box-shadow (which is deprecated already) or -webkit-box-shadow to apply only in chrome for example, can we do such a thing like -webkit-top:0 ?

This topic is according to mine: right [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089655/button-text-position-differs-from-browser)

So if there is some way to do so, then the another topic will be resolved...

Thank you.

Comment: If you are happy with a js/jquery solution, this is fantastic I have used it many times: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: which browser? and are you using any server side language?

Comment: No, i don't use any server side language right now. Browser is different. I need to specify for all browsers different parameters.

Comment: On a higher level, you may want to accept the fact that a website may render differently on different browsers.  This is okay by some advocates such as author Dan Cederholm (Bullet Proof Web Design).  Trying to make websites look pixel-to-pixel-perfect across all browsers can become expensive but some clients may be willing to pay extra to get that type of effect.  As an analogy, would a major music artist insist that his/her song sound the same on a $10K stereo system as it does on a $20 MP3 player?  Pobably not.

Comment: I agree with you Marc, but when this pixels or two going to text in button - it may ruin all the view of the button that you designed.

Comment: Are you talking about vendor specific properties, like -moz-border-radius etc? Or are you wanting to implement a global css property like margin, differently for different browsers?

Comment: I meant the second, but the explained it in post with the first one.

Comment: So it cannot be done using css alone. You need some way of using browser, platform, user agent detection etc, which the js file I linked to will offer. You can then prepend your styles with specific classes so .ie .target { background:red } will change the target to red on IE only.